# sorting dictionary by child key

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary, sorting

I understand how to display a dictionaries sorted content by means of obtaining allKeys into an NSMutableArray, sorting the array and using it as an index into the dictionary, but....

What if I want to sort the parent keys by one of their child keys?

for example, a dictionary with parent keys @"8979", @"6754", @8776", @"9076" and so on have child key / value pairs like:

@"pos", 8
@"pos", 4
@"pos", 10
@"pos", 7

and so on.

I know how to sort the parent keys to be: @"6754", @"8776", @"8979", @"9076"

but how to sort the parent keys based on their respective @"pos" child key resulting in:
@"6754", @"9076", @"8979", @"8776"

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` will let you supply a comparator that is passed the values from your dictionary and returns an ordered array of the keys.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this to a single line:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [keySort keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to do the trick for me ....

```
 NSArray *sortedArray = [keySort keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSString *p1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"pos"];
    NSString *p2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"pos"];

    if (p1 > p2 ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

    }

    if (p1 < p2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```